# Probability of having all $4$ Ace in a player?

Tags: probability

> From all $52$ playcards, now a person picks $13$ cards. What is the probability of having all $4$ Ace in his hand ?

Edit:
Many thanks for @Balajisb rather helpful reply first.

I've googled before and seen quite a few answers on Internet, one of them is Balaji sb's answer$\frac{\binom{48}{9}}{\binom{52}{13}}$, but not sure which one is correct.

I guess this ans means **no. of favorable outcomes divided by no. of total possible outcomes**.

Since $4$ out of $13$ cards must be the $4$ Ace, the varying part is the remaining $9$ cards on hand.

So no. of favorable outcomes = no. of combination of remaining 9 cards = $\binom{52-4}{9} = \binom{48}{9}$, which is the **numerator**.

The **denominator** is no. of total possible outcomes, which is simply take any $13$ cards from $52$, which is$ \binom{52}{13}$.

**But Some things that I don't understand about Balaji sb's answer are:**

1. Why just calculated as $$P(\text{get all 4 Ace}) = \frac{1}{52} \times\frac{1}{51}\times\frac{1}{50} \times\frac{1}{49} ~~~?$$  Why this thought is wrong ?
2. What is the difference between my wrong thought (point $1$) and Balaji sb's answer $\frac{\binom{48}{9}}{\binom{52}{13}}$ ?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: If you want to use SE you should understand why users here did not like the original question and the answer to it. This is not "solve homework for a cheater" site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer you proposed ($1/52\cdot 1/51 \cdot 1/50 \cdot 1/49$) does not take into account that you that you draw 13 cards; it assumes that 4 cards are drawn. Also, it assumes ordering of kings (say king of hearts followed by king of diamonds followed by ..). The correct answer to the question, as you noticed, is number of favorable outcomes divided by the number of total outcomes.

Answer (score 0):

First, the number of ways to select $4$ cards from $52$ is given by the combination $\binom{52}{4} = 270725$. This is the total number of possible $4$-card hands.

the number of hands that contain all four aces is $$4\times\binom{48}{1} = 4 \times48 = 192~.$$

the probability of a player being dealt all four aces is the ratio of the number of hands that contain all four aces to the total number of possible $4$-card hands:

$$P(\text{all four aces}) = \frac{192}{270725}$$

This simplifies to approximately $0.00071$, or about $1$ in $1409$. So the probability of a player being dealt all four aces is quite low.